# R Markdown kniter and LateX issue

Tags: r

Ok, so I am running into a very frustrating situation where I try a display a LaTeX table via RMD(kniter) and the output is commented out.  The result shows the LaTeX code, but not the table.

What am I missing?

````
  ---
  title: '2'
  author: "Aaron Soderstrom"
  date: "July 1, 2015"
  output: html_document
  ---

  ```{r }
  library('xtable')
  df <- data.frame(A = c(1.00123, 33.1, 6),B = c(111111, 3333333, 3123.233))

  print(xtable(df, display = c("s","f","f"), digits = 4),
  format.args = list(big.mark = " ", decimal.mark = ","))

  ```
````

Output:

```
print(xtable(df, display = c("s","f","f"), digits = 4),
format.args = list(big.mark = " ", decimal.mark = ","))
## % latex table generated in R 3.1.0 by xtable 1.7-4 package
## % Wed Jul 01 15:29:02 2015
## \begin{table}[ht]
## \centering
## \begin{tabular}{rrr}
##   \hline
##  & A & B \\ 
##   \hline
## 1 & 1,0012 & 111 111,0000 \\ 
##   2 & 33,1000 & 3 333 333,0000 \\ 
##   3 & 6,0000 & 3 123,2330 \\ 
##    \hline
## \end{tabular}
## \end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

````
```{r results='asis'}
  library('xtable')
  df <- data.frame(A = c(1.00123, 33.1, 6),B = c(111111, 3333333, 3123.233))

  print(xtable(df, display = c("s","f","f"), digits = 4),
  format.args = list(big.mark = " ", decimal.mark = ","),type="html")
```
````

Answer (score 2):

make sure the r chunk has

````
```{r results = 'asis'}
your code here
```
````